# TrueSkill Matchmaking Implementation

Tags: algorithm

**Hello!**

I was following this guide about how the Microsoft TrueSkill algorithm works http://www.moserware.com/2010/03/computing-your-skill.html The information is really good but leaves out how the actual selection of players should be done (which is obvious as this is unique for each game I guess).

My problem is that all algorithms that I come up with seems pretty complex (high time-complexity). Lets say I got 2 teams that should contain 4 players each. If I go brute force I need to check the match quality (following the trueskill algorithm) for all combinations that is currently available. This will lead to a huge number of iterations if there are a lot of players to take into account.

So I am asking you if you can give me any hints about how to do it smarter. Maybe you have stepped upon some information addressing this problem?

Comment: Actual details are laid out in Microsoft's article [TrueSkill™ Ranking System: Details](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/trueskill/details.aspx), especially the [Matchmaking](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/trueskill/details.aspx#Matchmaking) chapter. At the end of the MSDN article, there is also a link to a [F# implementation](http://blogs.technet.com/b/apg/archive/2008/06/16/trueskill-in-f.aspx).

Comment: Thank you for your time answering. Read about the matchmaking and yes the formula seems okey for calculating the draw probability, but I am interested in doing it in a fast way with a lot of players. I planned to do a broadphase sweep that will sort the players by their sigma in order to thrink the span of players, but I guess this would remove the purpose of the trueskill system.

Comment: TrueSkill is patented and a trademark, isn't it? http://www.google.com/patents/US20090227313

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I also implemented a matchmaking service with [the TrueSkill algorithm in Python](http://trueskill.org/) and I worried about same issue.

My matchmaking service waits to collect match requests for a while. Then it sorts requests by user's TrueSkill μ value and devides them. And waits again. It cannot find best match but it is fast. Here's a pseudo code:

```py
class Matchmaker(object):

    def matchmaking(self):
        sorted_pool = sorted(self.pool.itervalues(), key=by_rating)
        matches, self.pool = divide_uniformly(sorted_pool, expectation, minimum)
        return matches

    def run(self):
        while self.should_match():
            for match in self.matchmaking():
                if quality(match) < 0.5:
                    cancel(match)
                else:
                    succeed(match)
            time.sleep(self.interval)
```

p.s. You would need lots of users and a large match pool to get a benefit of rating system and matchmaking service.